# Css how to set 3 block block/div's in one line

Tags: html, css

My requirement is:

I want to place 3 div's in one line

like:-

```
  Name(h1)(leftside)    searchbox(form)(middle)  name2(divleft)(rightside)
```

I have done the jsfiddle code  ---[jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/4eLabjsv/)
But here these are not coming in one line..
what am I doing wrong??

Comment: Whic are the three divs that you want in single line? Can you mention the element ids from your jsfiddle example? Your html doesn't look correctly formatted btw.

Comment: Yes, but in that example, WHICH DIVs you want to place side by side?

Comment: I have edited the jsfiddle link..Now,I think you can understand..have "main" container..Where I want to put h1,searchbox and then divleft div's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to us float of divisions as follows:

```css
#container
{
    width:100%;
}

#left, #center, #right
{
    width:33.33%;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
}

#label1
{
     float:left;  
    margin-right:5px;
}

#input1
{
    float:left;   

}

#center
{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-top:30px;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="container"> 
    <div id="left"> <h1><a>Mycat </a></h1></div>
    <div id="center">  
            <form id="search" action="#" method="post">
                <div id="label1">
                    <label for="search-terms" id="search-label">search</label>                 </div>
                <div id="input1">
                        <input type="text" name="search-terms" id="search-terms" size="14" placeholder="Enter search terms...">
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>
    <div id="right"><h1><a>shipment </a></h1></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by floating your three elements.

```css
.block1 {
  float: left;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.block2 {
  float: left;
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.block3 {
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">
  <h1>Left</h1>
</div>

<div class="block2">
  <h1>Left</h1>
</div>

<div class="block3">
  <h1>Left</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: thats cool..But here I have a container which contains 3 div's..now,what I to use?

Comment: You can see 3 divs in a container here - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyXRzg

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use flexbox. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.block1, .block2, .block3 {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.block1 {
  background: red;
}

.block2 {
  background: blue;
}

.block3 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="block1">
    <h1>Left</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="block2">
    <h1>Left</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="block3">
    <h1>Left</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

See the updated [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4eLabjsv/1/) here. Understand, I have not cleaned the code properly, just made changes to make it work as you want.

The html and css given are malformed, needs quite a clean-up to make things right. Here is a slightly better version.

```
<main>
    <h1>
        <a>Mycat</a> <!-- why anchor? -->
    </h1>
    <form id="search" action="#" method="post">
        <span id="label1">
            <label for="search-terms" id="search-label">search</label>
        </span>
        <span id="input1">
            <input type="text" name="search-terms" id="search-terms" placeholder="Enter search terms..." />
        </span>
    </form>
    <div id="divleft""> 
        <h1>
            <a>shipment</a> <!-- why anchor? -->
        </h1>
    </div> 
</main>
```

And the main change in css is

```
#divleft {
    float: right;
    /*margin-top: 15px;*/
    display:inline-block;
}
#search {
    /*position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-left: -60px;*/
    margin-left: 15px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Use float if you really want to float elements (even on top of each other). To keep in same line display: inline/inline-block should work. It let's place other elements adjacent to them.

You can add your cpecific height, width back to the css if you really want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code in which 3 div's placed in one line and middle div is flexible

HTML:

```
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
<div class="middle"><div class="form">middle form</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.left{
    background:red;
    min-width:70px;
    float:left;

}
.middle{
    background:yellow;

}
.right{
    float:right;
    min-width:70px;
    background:green
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left` to force block elements to be side by side.  Then `clear: left` to end the floating.

Comment: where I have to use this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ze4txbrc/2/ example showing how to place block elements side by side.